# Tradingview Intrabar Price Emulation Behaviour

Tags: algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I understand that TradingView price emulation for intrabar calculations uses the following two estimates to emulate the movement of price:

> 1. If the bar’s high is closer to bar’s open than the bar’s low, the broker emulator assumes that intrabar price was moving this way: open → high → low → close.

> 2. If the bar’s low is closer to bar’s open than the bar’s high, the broker emulator assumes that intrabar price was moving this way: open → low → high → close.

However I'm confused about what would happen in the following situation :

If we have two limit orders , order 1 (red line) order 2 (blue line), given the bar’s high is closer to bar’s open than the bar’s low, would order 1 always execute after order 2? i.e. **open -> order 2 price -> order 1 price -> high -> low -> close**

I ask this because the emulator estimates it will go from open -> high first, but does it ever consider that orders can execute after dropping from the high down to the low i.e. **open -> order 1  price -> high -> order 2 price -> open -> low -> close**

*(y axis is price, x is time)*

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both orders will be executed during moving open -> high in this case, and Order 1 is after Order 2. Orders on high -> low will be executed only if they prices are less than open.